# How to upload a document from a unix box to a HTTP?

Tags: http, unix

How to upload a document from a unix box to an HTTP? Preferably using wget(not curl)

Comment: have look here, i guess its what you are searching for: https://superuser.com/questions/86043/linux-command-line-tool-for-uploading-files-over-http-as-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

Reason in terms of the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol and HTTP [requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields). Yo probably want to do some [HTTP `POST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request (in rare cases, it might be a `PUT` request). You need to understand precisely which request should be done (and with which [HTTP cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)!). If some [HTML form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_(HTML)) is involved, you need to identify and understand what HTTP request is it doing, so read more about [`<input` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) in HTML (some of them might be of [`<input type='hidden'`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp)). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007969/841108) about `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).

Then you need an HTTP client capable of issuing such a request. GNU [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html) can't do `POST` (unless you use some [`--post`* options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html)), only `GET`. But [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) can do both.

You could also write some script or program doing that request. Using some HTTP client library (like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) is helpful.